# Firebase Firestore where clause returning empty resultset for flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to write a `where` query on a collection in firebase firestore. I have a test field in a document in the collection called `myValue`. When I query where `myValue "==" true` in the firestore console, I get back my document. See the image attached [image: Search Result From the console]. The problem is, when I run the same query in Flutter and get snapshots from it, I receive no data back. What could be going wrong? Here is how I declare the reference:

```
allChatsQuery = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('chats')
    .where("myValue", isEqualTo: true);
```

And here is how I try to access the results:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<dynamic>>(
    stream: GetXController.to.allChatsQuery!.snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
    // null checks, serialization and widget return

}
```

Comment: Print the error in `snapshot.error` and add it to the question please

Comment: @MoazEl-sawaf There is no error caught by the snapshot

Comment: if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()),
            );
          }

          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } it would have been caught in the builder here

Comment: can you provide more code snippet?

Comment: Can you try this? `allChatsQuery = FirebaseFirestore.instance`
                                                `.where("myValue", isEqualTo: true) .getDocuments( ).documents;`